# Unable to access enum key outside of the class

Tags: java, enums, java-8, code-readability

Following is my Helper provider class

```
    public class HP<T> implements javax.inject.Provider<T> {
   private static Map<KEY, Object> helperMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void setHelper(KEY helper, Object helperObject) {
        helperMap.put(helper, helperObject);
    }

        public static enum KEY {
            POLICY_HELPER, MILES_HELPER;
        }
    }
```

and i am initializing map

```
class AAAA{
static {
initHelperProviderMap();
}
    private static void initHelperProviderMap() {
            HP.KEY. **//Unable to access enum KEY's key POLICY_HELPER etc** 
            HP.setHelper(HP.KEY.??, helperObject);


        }
```

here HP.KEY.POLICY_HELPER is unaccessible to me. can you please suggest any solution ?

Comment: why dont you move the KEY  to its own file?

Comment: can be done but that's not the solution for this problem

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference but try removing `static` from `public static enum KEY ` as it is not necessary.

Comment: Yes Enums are by default static correct. anyway i have moved out KEY to new file. and i am able to access it. something with HP<?>

Comment: I've copied your code, but it seems it is working to me, or at least my IDE does not complain about it.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ  Thanks

Comment: @OlarAndrei if that's the case, then this question should be closed as it can not be re-produced.

Comment: I don’t see any reason why this shouldn’t work, unless there’s something you haven’t posted, like a variable named `HP` or `KEY` being in scope. That’s why you should adhere to the naming convention, i.e. use all-uppercase names for static variables (constants) only and mixed case names for classes…